# OperationalError: near "%": syntax error with sqlite3 in Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, syntax, operationalerror

I'm using the `sqlite3` package in Python and trying to select a single entry from a table called `orders`. I would like to get the entry where the value for column `order_date` ends in 18 (it's a `varchar` column where the actual value of this entry is "10/20/2018").

As per the guidance on similar questions, I've constructed the query as follows:

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM orders
            WHERE order_date LIKE %s"""

args = ['%' + '18']

c.execute(sql, args)
```

But I get this back:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-e6a345ebe6eb> in <module>
      6 args = ['%' + '18']
      7 
----> 8 c.execute(sql, args)
      9 conn.commit()
     10 

OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

I've tried structuring the query a number of ways, but get the same error every time. According to the other questions I've browsed, this should work. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `?`as a placeholder for a binding variable instead of `%s`:

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM orders
            WHERE order_date LIKE ?"""
```